# Workarounds for / alternatives for EF4 that work with Oracle PL/SQL procedures and record types as functions?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, plsql

We've got several legacy appliations based on Delphi and Oracle PL/SQL stored procedures. 
Some of these procedures take a PL/SQL record as parameter, e.g.:

```
create or replace package pck_search is

  type SearchParamsRecType is record(
    search_id       pls_integer,
    search_database pls_integer,
    search_mode     pls_integer,
    result_mode     pls_integer,
    wild_card       pls_integer);

  procedure PerformQuickSearch(p_cursor    in out sys_refcursor,
                               p_parameter in SearchParamsRecType);

end pck_search;
```

We now want to add a web-based client (ASP.Net MVC4), but we ran into some issues with this kind of stored procedures. When I try to import the stored procedure using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, I get this error message:

```
The function 'PCK_SEARCH.PERFORMQUICKSEARCH' has a parameter 
'P_PARAMETER' at parameter index 0 that has a data type 'pl/sql record' 
which is currently not supported for the target .NET Framework version. 
The function was excluded.
```

Googling for the error message returned only [one hit from 2010](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=18243) - the answer then was "this is not possible".

So, my question boils down to:

- Is it possible to import Oracle PL/SQL stored procedures that take a record type as parameter using the Entity Framework?
- Are there any alternatives for the Entity Framework that can handle this kind of stored procedures?

Comment: Have you found an answer to make this work?

Comment: @Kar We switched to Object Types (as suggested by HAL9000 in their answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish between "PL/SQL Records", "PL/SQL RowTypes" and "SQL Object Types".

Records and Rowtypes are Oracle-specifics and only accessable from PL/SQL - so they're out of scope for EF, which uses basicly SQL.

That's why you'd have to use object types (or "user-defined types" as Oracle calls them).

Here is an extensive piece of documentation about [Oracle User-Defined Types (UDTs) and .NET Custom Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14435_01/win.111/e10927/featUDTs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this answer only if no other is available. I'm not an adept at MVC yet, so I can't advise there, but on the Oracle end you can make things palatable to MVC by using wrapper procedures that accept data types MVC understands.

Note that I don't have the ability to test a `CREATE PACKAGE` right now so the following is from memory. I won't vouch for the syntax but hopefully the general idea is apparent.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pck_wrap_search IS

  PROCEDURE PerformQuickSearch(
    p_cursor in out sys_refcursor,
    -- If MVC doesn't like pls_integer you could make these NUMBER values
    search_id       pls_integer,
    search_database pls_integer,
    search_mode     pls_integer,
    result_mode     pls_integer,
    wild_card       pls_integer);
  END PerformQuickSearch;

END pck_wrap_search;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pck_wrap_search IS

  PROCEDURE PerformQuickSearch(
    p_cursor in out sys_refcursor,
    search_id       pls_integer,
    search_database pls_integer,
    search_mode     pls_integer,
    result_mode     pls_integer,
    wild_card       pls_integer)
  IS
    -- I'm not sure if you need to initialize this somehow.
    searchParams pck_search.SearchParamsRecType;
  BEGIN
    -- Assemble the type that the "real" proc needs
    searchParams.search_id       := search_id;
    searchParams.search_database := search_database;
    searchParams.search_mode     := search_mode;
    searchParams.result_mode     := result_mode;
    searchParams.wild_card       := wild_card;
    -- Call the "real" proc
    pck_search.PerformQuickSearch(p_cursor, searchParams);
  END PerformQuickSearch;

END pck_wrap_search;
```

With this approach, your MVC would call the `pck_wrap_search.PerformQuickSearch` wrapper using "simple" data types, and the wrapper puts the "simple" types into the Oracle type and calls the "real" function. It's not pretty, and it's not a silver bullet, but it should work and it won't require messing with the existing packages.

Comment: Thanks. I think this should work, but I'd prefer not having to create extra wrapper packages, so I will use this approach only as a last resort.

Comment: You're welcome, and I agree - this is a last-resort solution only. Good luck!